# SSL configuration between kafka and zookeeper

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I need to secure my zookeeper with SSL and then configure kafka broker to access to zookeeper with ssl.

Is it possible ?
And if yes, how ?

Thanks
Alain

Comment: Welcome to the site. To help us answer your questions better, please check out these links: [ask]  and [tour]

Comment: Please refer [this recent mail thread on your subject](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/zookeeper-user/201612.mbox/<HE1PR07MB1721DFB05C2EF20F0B2C799D8B9A0%40HE1PR07MB1721.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com>)

Comment: From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447220/kafka-zookeeper-security) current version of zookeeper supports only SASL.

Comment: This is possible thru a workaround I have mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493064/3377881