# Kafka Zookeeper security

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

I am using Kafka Version 0.10.2.0. Is there a way to secure communication between Zookeper Client i.e ZkClient and zookeper server with SSL. I found some way to do through SASL but i want it through SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zookeeper 3.5 includes SSL support but it is still in alpha so Kafka doesn't yet support it. The highest supported version is 3.4 which only includes sasl.

Ref: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1000

Answer (score 1):

This task can still be achieved by a simple workaround mentioned in the steps below;

1. Install zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha (to use the .jar files. version 3.5+ can be used)
2. Replace default zookeeper*.jar with `/zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha/zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha.jar` in `<kafka-installation-folder>\libs`
3. Copy `/zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha/lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar` into `<kafka-installation-folder>\libs`
4. Relevant changes to enable SSL on Zookeeper (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ZooKeeper+SSL+User+Guide)